# Is there a more efficient way to override these fields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I currently have two tables, let's call them "Template" and Instance" in a MySQL database. The Instances can be linked to a Template, which causes some of the fields to be overridden by the fields from the Template. When the Instance becomes unlinked, the fields from the Instance will be used. The Instance has extra fields which aren't in the Template and vice-versa.

```
Template
id
fieldA
fieldB
```

```
Instance
id
linkedTemplateId
fieldA
fieldC
```

Currently, my selects look like:

```
SELECT
Instance.id,
IF(Instance.linkedTemplateId IS NULL, Instance.fieldA, Template.fieldA) AS fieldA,
Instance.fieldC
FROM Instance LEFT JOIN Template ON Instance.linkedTemplateID=Template.id;
```

There are quite a few fields in the actual statement, so a lot of `IF`s, and the `SELECT`s are performed quite often. It's one of the top SQL statements reported in AWS's performance insights, so I'm trying to see if there's a way to optimise it. Is there a better way to do it? I'm not using COALESCE as I want to have Template nulls override the Instance field, otherwise I could use `COALESCE(Template.fieldA, Instance.fieldA)`. I'm not even sure if the IFs are causing the performance issue, but I suspect they're causing some high CPU usage on the RDS instance we're using.

***Edit***

Here is the output of `EXPLAIN` for the query:

```
> EXPLAIN SELECT  
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.userID, TaskList.userID) AS `userID`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.name, TaskList.name) AS `name`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.categoryID, TaskList.categoryID) AS `categoryID`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.priority, TaskList.priority) AS `priority`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.defaultLanguage, TaskList.defaultLanguage) AS `defaultLanguage`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.tabletPIN, TaskList.tabletPIN) AS `tabletPIN`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.autoApproval, TaskList.autoApproval) AS `autoApproval`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.trackCosts, TaskList.trackCosts) AS `trackCosts`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.labourCost, TaskList.labourCost) AS `labourCost`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.labourCostUnit, TaskList.labourCostUnit) AS `labourCostUnit`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.displayLabourCostToAssignee, TaskList.displayLabourCostToAssignee) AS `displayLabourCostToAssignee`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.assigneeUpdatesLabourCost, TaskList.assigneeUpdatesLabourCost) AS `assigneeUpdatesLabourCost`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.partsCost, TaskList.partsCost) AS `partsCost`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.displayPartsCostToAssignee, TaskList.displayPartsCostToAssignee) AS `displayPartsCostToAssignee`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.assigneeUpdatesPartsCost, TaskList.assigneeUpdatesPartsCost) AS `assigneeUpdatesPartsCost`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.trackTiming, TaskList.trackTiming) AS `trackTiming`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.completionTimingDays, TaskList.completionTimingDays) AS `completionTimingDays`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.completionTimingHours, TaskList.completionTimingHours) AS `completionTimingHours`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.completionTimingMinutes, TaskList.completionTimingMinutes) AS `completionTimingMinutes`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.deadlineType, TaskList.deadlineType) AS `deadlineType`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.displayTimer, TaskList.displayTimer) AS `displayTimer`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.displayBookingDetails, TaskList.displayBookingDetails) AS `displayBookingDetails`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.displayCustomBookingDetails, TaskList.displayCustomBookingDetails) AS `displayCustomBookingDetails`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.displayPropertyDetails, TaskList.displayPropertyDetails) AS `displayPropertyDetails`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.displayCustomPropertyDetails, TaskList.displayCustomPropertyDetails) AS `displayCustomPropertyDetails`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.showPriorBooking, TaskList.showPriorBooking) AS `showPriorBooking`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.showActiveBooking, TaskList.showActiveBooking) AS `showActiveBooking`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.showNextBooking, TaskList.showNextBooking) AS `showNextBooking`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.showGuestName, TaskList.showGuestName) AS `showGuestName`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.showGuestTelNumber, TaskList.showGuestTelNumber) AS `showGuestTelNumber`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.showNumGuests, TaskList.showNumGuests) AS `showNumGuests`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.showArrivalDepartureDates, TaskList.showArrivalDepartureDates) AS `showArrivalDepartureDates`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.showIntroOutro, TaskList.showIntroOutro) AS `showIntroOutro`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.propertyCleaningStatus, TaskList.propertyCleaningStatus) AS `propertyCleaningStatus`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.isGroupedList, TaskList.isGroupedList) AS `isGroupedList`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.isSingleTask, TaskList.isSingleTask) AS `isSingleTask`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.showGuides, TaskList.showGuides) AS `showGuides`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.issuesUserID, TaskList.issuesUserID) AS `issuesUserID`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.approvalUserID, TaskList.approvalUserID) AS `approvalUserID`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.delayCleanStatusUntilApproval, TaskList.delayCleanStatusUntilApproval) AS `delayCleanStatusUntilApproval`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.assignTo, TaskList.assignTo) AS `assignTo`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.assigneeDisplayDelayType, TaskList.assigneeDisplayDelayType) AS `assigneeDisplayDelayType`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.assigneeDisplayDelay, TaskList.assigneeDisplayDelay) AS `assigneeDisplayDelay`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.assigneeDisplayDelayUnit, TaskList.assigneeDisplayDelayUnit) AS `assigneeDisplayDelayUnit`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.departmentAssignType, TaskList.departmentAssignType) AS `departmentAssignType`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.groups, TaskList.groups) AS `groups`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.groupByDepartment, TaskList.groupByDepartment) AS `groupByDepartment`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.groupByDepartmentID, TaskList.groupByDepartmentID) AS `groupByDepartmentID`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.notificationGroupID, TaskList.notificationGroupID) AS `notificationGroupID`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.createdByUserID, TaskList.createdByUserID) AS `createdByUserID`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.allowAcceptDecline, TaskList.allowAcceptDecline) AS `allowAcceptDecline`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.showCompleteAllButton, TaskList.showCompleteAllButton) AS `showCompleteAllButton`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.overdueEmailEnabled, TaskList.overdueEmailEnabled) AS `overdueEmailEnabled`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.enabledPropertyDetails, TaskList.enabledPropertyDetails) AS `enabledPropertyDetails`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.priorBookingOptions, TaskList.priorBookingOptions) AS `priorBookingOptions`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.activeBookingOptions, TaskList.activeBookingOptions) AS `activeBookingOptions`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.nextBookingOptions, TaskList.nextBookingOptions) AS `nextBookingOptions`,
IF(ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID IS NULL, ScheduledTaskList.ignoreAvailability, TaskList.ignoreAvailability) AS `ignoreAvailability`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`listID`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`archived`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`deleted`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`createdTime`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`updatedTime`,
`Creator`.`userID` AS `creatorSummary.userID`,
`CreatorUser`.`email` AS `creatorSummary.email`,
`Creator`.`firstName` AS `creatorSummary.firstName`,
`Creator`.`lastName` AS `creatorSummary.lastName`,
`CreatorAvatar`.`imageID` AS `creatorSummary.avatarID`,
`CreatorAvatar`.`imagePath` AS `creatorSummary.avatarPath`,
`CreatorAvatar`.`name` AS `creatorSummary.avatarName`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`assignedUserID`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`assignedDepartmentID`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`propertyID`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`bookingID`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`generatedDate`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`scheduledDate`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`startDate`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`visibleDate`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`dueDate`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`accepted`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`acceptedDate`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`declined`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`declinedDate`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`declinedAssigneeUserIDs`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`status`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`timer`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`linkedListID`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`originalListID`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`assignedDate`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`notifyAssigneeDate`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`assigneeNotified`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`completedDate`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`startedDate`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`sentAssignedNotification`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`sentOverdueNotification`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`sentUnclaimedNotification`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`scheduledDateOffset`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`scheduledDateOffsetFrom`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`overrideTemplateDates`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`overrideAssignedUser`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`isIssue`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`additionalInfo`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`issuesListID`,
`ScheduledTaskList`.`approvalListID`,
`Property`.`propertyID` AS `propertySummary.propertyID`,
`Property`.`nickname` AS `propertySummary.nickname`,
`Property`.`timezone` AS `propertySummary.timezone`,
`Property`.`addressLine1` AS `propertySummary.addressLine1`,
`Property`.`addressLine2` AS `propertySummary.addressLine2`,
`Property`.`addressCity` AS `propertySummary.addressCity`,
`Property`.`addressCounty` AS `propertySummary.addressCounty`,
`Property`.`addressCountry` AS `propertySummary.addressCountry`,
`Property`.`postcode` AS `propertySummary.postcode`,
`Property`.`userID` AS `propertySummary.userID`,
`Property`.`cleaningStatus` AS `propertySummary.cleaningStatus`,
`Assignee`.`userID` AS `assigneeSummary.userID`,
`AssigneeUser`.`email` AS `assigneeSummary.email`,
`Assignee`.`firstName` AS `assigneeSummary.firstName`,
`Assignee`.`lastName` AS `assigneeSummary.lastName`,
`AssigneeAvatar`.`imageID` AS `assigneeSummary.avatarID`,
`AssigneeAvatar`.`imagePath` AS `assigneeSummary.avatarPath`,
`AssigneeAvatar`.`name` AS `assigneeSummary.avatarName`
FROM ScheduledTaskList
LEFT JOIN Property USING (propertyID)
LEFT JOIN PropertyGroup ON Property.propertyGroupID=PropertyGroup.groupID
LEFT JOIN TaskList ON ScheduledTaskList.linkedListID=TaskList.listID
LEFT JOIN CompanyUser AS Assignee ON ScheduledTaskList.userID=Assignee.companyID AND ScheduledTaskList.assignedUserID=Assignee.userID
LEFT JOIN User AS AssigneeUser ON ScheduledTaskList.assignedUserID=AssigneeUser.userID
LEFT JOIN Image AS AssigneeAvatar ON Assignee.avatarID=AssigneeAvatar.imageID
LEFT JOIN CompanyUser AS Creator ON ScheduledTaskList.userID=Creator.companyID AND ScheduledTaskList.createdByUserID=Creator.userID
LEFT JOIN User AS CreatorUser ON ScheduledTaskList.createdByUserID=CreatorUser.userID
LEFT JOIN Image AS CreatorAvatar ON Creator.avatarID=CreatorAvatar.imageID
WHERE (ScheduledTaskList.originalListID IN (1984)) 
AND (ScheduledTaskList.propertyID=232) 
AND (ScheduledTaskList.deleted=0 OR ScheduledTaskList.deleted IS NULL) 
AND (Property.archived=false) 
ORDER BY listID asc 
LIMIT 9007199254740991 
OFFSET 0

******************** 1. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Property
   partitions: 
         type: const
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: 
******************** 2. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: PropertyGroup
   partitions: 
         type: const
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: 
      key_len: 
          ref: 
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Impossible ON condition
******************** 3. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ScheduledTaskList
   partitions: 
         type: ref
possible_keys: ScheduledTaskList_PropertyID_idx,ScheduledTaskList_OriginalListID_idx
          key: ScheduledTaskList_OriginalListID_idx
      key_len: 5
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 5.00
        Extra: Using where
******************** 4. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: TaskList
   partitions: 
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: DB.ScheduledTaskList.LinkedListID
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: 
******************** 5. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Assignee
   partitions: 
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,CompanyUser_UserID_idx
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: DB.ScheduledTaskList.UserID,DB.ScheduledTaskList.AssignedUserID
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: 
******************** 6. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: AssigneeUser
   partitions: 
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: DB.ScheduledTaskList.AssignedUserID
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: 
******************** 7. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: AssigneeAvatar
   partitions: 
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,ImageID_UNIQUE
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: DB.Assignee.AvatarID
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: 
******************** 8. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Creator
   partitions: 
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,CompanyUser_UserID_idx
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: DB.ScheduledTaskList.UserID,DB.ScheduledTaskList.CreatedByUserID
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: 
******************** 9. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: CreatorUser
   partitions: 
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: DB.ScheduledTaskList.CreatedByUserID
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: 
******************** 10. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: CreatorAvatar
   partitions: 
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,ImageID_UNIQUE
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: DB.Creator.AvatarID
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: 
10 rows in set
```

Comment: Before worrying about the `IF()` expressions, I would make sure your `JOIN` is optimized with an index. The query you show will at least do one table-scan because there is no `WHERE` clause with a condition. But it would be far worse if it has to do a table-scan of the joined table as well, for lack of an index.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT ....(your complete query)..; so we have some idea how many of your selections do not have the advantage of an index for matching purposes.